# Debugging slow internet connection

Tags: isp, internet-speed

I've been experiencing a slow internet connection for the past couple of days.

Using torrents to measure the speed, it has gone from about 400 kB/s to about 50 kB/s.

I've already checked all "slow internet connection" posts I could find on this site, but none of them help me because I believe I've already discarded all posibilities described in the answers to those questions. Here's what I was able to verify:

- It's not a wireless problem. It happens on a laptop that's connected via wire to my router, which is connected via wire to my modem, which is connected via wire to the phone line.
- It's not a device-specific problem. It happens on multiple devices connected to the network, wire or not.
- It's not a router problem. Transfering a file via LAN is very fast (~1 MB/s+).
- It's not a program stealing all the bandwidth. I disable wireless on my router, connect only my laptop via wire, and verify no sketchy program is accessing the internet with [GlassWire](https://www.glasswire.com/), the problem still persists.

speedtest.net says ping of 238ms, upload of 0.59 Mbps, and download of 0.35 Mbps.

All I can think of now is that my ISP is screwing with me.

What can I do to further debug or fix this problem?

Here's a `pathping` output:

```
% pathping google.com

Tracing route to google.com [200.40.0.85]
over a maximum of 30 hops:
  0  x-PC [192.168.1.101]
  1  192.168.1.1
  2     *        *        *
Computing statistics for 25 seconds...
            Source to Here   This Node/Link
Hop  RTT    Lost/Sent = Pct  Lost/Sent = Pct  Address
  0                                           x-PC [192.168.1.101]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  1    0ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  192.168.1.1

Trace complete.
```

Honestly doesn't seem very insightful (maybe I should run with certain flag?) so here's a `tracert` as well:

```
% tracert google.com

Tracing route to google.com [200.40.0.82]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3    26 ms    26 ms    26 ms  cen1bras1.antel.net.uy [200.40.17.3]
  4    25 ms    26 ms    26 ms  ibb2cen4-0-4-90.antel.net.uy [200.40.17.161]
  5    28 ms    27 ms    27 ms  cbb2une1-be150.antel.net.uy [200.40.162.5]
  6    28 ms    27 ms    28 ms  ibe2uni1-be150.antel.net.uy [200.40.162.6]
  7    27 ms    26 ms    27 ms  ibb2uni1-1-2.antel.net.uy [200.40.16.217]
  8    26 ms    26 ms    27 ms  ibb2agu1-2-2-0.antel.net.uy [200.40.16.181]
  9    26 ms    26 ms    24 ms  isv2agu2-1-49.antel.net.uy [200.40.72.34]
 10    26 ms    26 ms    26 ms  cache.google.com [200.40.0.82]

Trace complete.
```

Another `tracert`:

```
% tracert bbc.co.uk

Tracing route to bbc.co.uk [212.58.246.104]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3    26 ms    26 ms    26 ms  cen1bras1.antel.net.uy [200.40.17.3]
  4    26 ms    26 ms    26 ms  ibb2cen3-0-4-90.antel.net.uy [200.40.17.33]
  5    31 ms    27 ms    28 ms  cbb2une1-be150.antel.net.uy [200.40.162.5]
  6    27 ms    27 ms    28 ms  ibe2uni1-be150.antel.net.uy [200.40.162.6]
  7   166 ms   167 ms   167 ms  ibr2nap4-0-2-1-0.antel.net.uy [200.40.16.178]
  8   178 ms   178 ms   178 ms  sl-st50-mia-.sprintlink.net [144.223.67.101]
  9   191 ms   185 ms   183 ms  sl-st50-mia-.sprintlink.net [144.232.2.237]
 10   182 ms   182 ms   182 ms  te-4-1.car4.Miami1.Level3.net [4.68.62.77]
 11   264 ms   262 ms   263 ms  ae-231-3607.edge4.London1.Level3.net [4.69.166.25]
 12   280 ms   279 ms   281 ms  BBC-TECHNOL.edge4.London1.Level3.net [212.113.14.222]
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15   279 ms   274 ms   273 ms  ae0.er02.cwwtf.bbc.co.uk [132.185.254.90]
 16   284 ms   284 ms   284 ms  132.185.255.165
 17   291 ms   291 ms   285 ms  fmt-vip133.cwwtf.bbc.co.uk [212.58.246.104]

Trace complete.
```

Comment: Did you restart your router? Please edit your question to include the results of a traceroute (even better [pathping](http://ss64.com/nt/pathping.html) if you have access to it) from your PC to a well known site (eg www.google.com). Do this from your laptop with a **wired** connection (and no other internet activity).

Comment: Some ISPs throttle torrents specifically

Comment: Did you call your ISP? Do you have a cap/limit?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I know that, it's not the case for my ISP. Internet is slow in general, I just use torrents as a general measurement.

Comment: @DavidPostill I did restart my router, as well as my modem. Didn't change anything. I edited my post with a traceroute and a pathping.

Comment: @Dave I did not call my ISP yet. I'd prefer not having to deal with them, though I might have to eventually. I don't have a download cap if that's what you're asking.

Comment: I would ask the ISP. Since you can use everything fine internally, you need to get them to test the line and do all the tests they do. To be sure though, test on multiple broadband checkers to be sure they're all saying the same thing (to give yourself a better argument against the ISP)

Comment: Strange that hop 2 is not responding properly. What do you get from http://www.pingtest.net/

Comment: Can you try tracert to somehere off antel.net.uy eg www.bbc.co.uk

Comment: @DavidPostill Well, pingtest.net says 0% packet loss, 55ms ping, and 0ms jitter, but it's kind of worth nothing because it tests against a very close server. Testing against a far away one I get 241ms ping and 1ms jitter, but still 0% packet loss. Also, I added a traceroute to bbc.co.uk.

Comment: you tried pingtest, but did you try speedtest.net? Try the default location for reference, then test again to Miami, New York & London, see if you get significant drops to those - you will always see some drop. Logically, the route will go uy>miami>lon so NY would just add another reference point off your chosen path. [Default server is 'local', Preferred server will give you a map you can drag & zoom to pick a specific city]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I called my ISP.

They had me connect the computer directly to the modem for some reason, and do a speed test with [their own speed testing website](http://www.adsltest.com.uy). When the result was low (about 0.70 Mbps), they told me the complaint had been filed.

I was contacted about half an hour later and told that the problem wasn't the speed, but rather that the connecton was intermittent (?), which honestly seems like B.S., but I was also told that if I tested now, the speed should come out fine, which surpisingly it did.

So everything seems to be back to normal now. They also told me they would send a technician to fix the intermittent issue but I don't know if that will be needed (I doubt this "intermittent issue" exists).

Bottom line is, when you've discarded all other possibilities, just call your ISP.

Thanks everyone for your help.